# Restore lost partitions of a Hard Disk caused by image writing

Tags: hard-drive, partition-recovery

I have an external hard disk of 1TB. By fault, I have opened an image of my own SD Card (using a software under Windows 8) and clicked on "write" button. Then I stopped it immediately. But I was shocked that all partitions has been lost within a few seconds of flushing the image.

> is there any way to restore partitions cause by image writing? And why the size if hard disk become as the size of SD Card (because of the mentioned image)?
>
> > I have tried a stronge software called "TestDisk" but all attempts failed sadly.

Comment: Based on the tools you have already tried you have already tried your best hope.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how the 1TB disk was partitioned? Was it only a data dump disk with one partition? What filesystem was on it? NTFS?

NTFS file systems usually have a backup boot sector at the last sector of the partition. If the disk had only one partition, you would find that at roughly the end of the disk. You might want to use a disk hex editor for this: open the disk (usually there is a special option for opening disks instead of regular files), and have a look at the end of the disk. Somewhere, there should be a sector where at the first few bytes there is the string "NTFS". That would be the backup sector you’re looking for.

If the last sector on the disk has the string "EFI PART", then you have a GPT partitioned disk, which makes creating a partition table from scratch (only with the hex editor) a bit tricky.

Assume you don’t find the "EFI PART" string, but the NTFS string somewhere on the last sectors, then do the following:

a) create a new empty MBR partition table (deleting the last 66 bytes of sector 0 and putting in 55 AA in the last two bytes of sector 0)
b) create a new partition entry (starting 66 bytes before the end) with the following values:
    00 00 FF FF FF 07 FF FF FF 00 08 00 00 XX XX XX XX
The last 4 bytes (XX XX XX XX) really depend on the disk size and should match the value plus 1 that you found in the NTFS backup sector at offset 0x28 
c) now copy and paste the backup NTFS boot sector to sector 2048.

Default location of the NTFS master file table (MFT) is at cluster C0000, which is 3 GB into the disk. So if you really stopped the writing of the SD image to the disk, chances are high that the MFT itself is still intact. 
What probably is damaged is the Volume Bitmap and the Mirror MFT, but these can usually be fixed by a run of chkdsk (or scandisk).

The testdisk program might have a hard time finding anything, because you overwrote the start of the disk with a valid new file system (at least partially), so it probably doesn’t really try to find a foreign Master File Table somewhere.

Comment: Thank you so much. .. I'll try that .. concerning your first question: I have two partitions 600Gb and 350Gb

Comment: If that is the case, then the partition later in the disk should still be available in its entirety. But you need to look for it. A hex tool will be necessary for this. Navigate to roughly 600GB (a bit earlier than that) and look for sectors that have the string "NTFS" (in upper case) on the bytes 3, 4, 5 and 6 (if you start counting at 0). Note down all the sector positions where you find such sectors. Ideally, you should find the backup NTFS sector for the first partition immediately before the NTFS sector for the 2nd partition. Then you know length of partition 1 and start of partition 2.

Comment: Actually, there many things to do ... I'll try that when I finish my exams. Finally,  I don't know how to thank you. .. I'll be grateful if you give some links for those technologies to improve my skills ... thanks again